# Can I merge two chromium based browsers?

Tags: browser, chromium

I have two chromium-based browsers each having its own benefits, I want both of them in one. Is it possible?Any help?

I need anonimity(epic browser) and torrent download feature( torch browser) in one browser, so I thought merging these two would be a good idea. Getting thier source code and modifying it to create our own. Is it feasible?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the features added by you? If yes then obviously you can take one as base browser and implement(copy code) the other feature in the base browser. Is there any problem in that?

Comment: No, these are available from their site as it is. I can ask them for their codes and implement. Well thanks for ur comment.